# Suggestions for setting up a subversion repository

Tags: svn, version-control

Our team is just ramping up to use source control through SVN. We are currently using some test repositories for getting used to the process.

We're nearly ready to put this into full time use.

We build only small to medum/large web apps, most of which share the same core (but differnt on LAMP/Win), but are customized in some way. We will likely have hundreds of projects in the repository. Also, we usually do more than one project for one organization.

We have LAMP and Windows developers. ( I  think this makes the question somewhat different than [Best practice for creating subversion repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167014/best-practice-for-creating-subversion-repositories))

Do you have any suggestions on how to structure the repository?

Comment: I actually think that having Linux and Windows develoeprs doesn't change the question at all from the one you linked to. All of those answers apply just the same. (which is one of the points of source control - it doesn't matter what your client OS is!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you structure your repo will probably depend a lot on the release cycle. When you do a new version of your common core, will you roll it out to all your customers at once? Or will you do incremental roll-out as each customer needs new features (and, therefore, has need of the new features in the core)?

If you'll roll out to everyone when you upgrade your core, then you probably want one set of branches/tags/trunk:

```
branches/
tags/
trunk/
    core/
    customer1/
        project1/
        project2/
    customer2/
        project1/
        project2/
```

The downside to this is that, if there's a lot of code for each customer, your checkouts would be huge, and you'd have to check out everything to be able to do anything (though svn 1.6 does give you the ability to check out a subset of the tree).

On the other hand, if the different customers will be released on different schedules, then you might prefer to have a top-level directory for each customer. You'd also want someplace to keep your common core.

```
core/
    branches/
    tags/
    trunk/
customer1/
    branches/
    tags/
    trunk/
```

If you do this, you'd probably want to look into `svn:external` so you get a copy of the common core whenever you check out customer1's source tree. This causes some issues when you want to branch or tag, though. (Which might be a reason to prefer the first option.)

If you haven't yet, read "[Pragmatic Version Control Using Subversion](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/svn2/pragmatic-version-control-using-subversion)". They have some examples of using externals, which might help clarify which scheme you want to use.

Comment: Most of the svn:external issues go away if you use an explicit revision indicator in the svn:external definition. Your tags stay stable this way, and upgrading to a newer version of core requires an explicit commit to change the svn:external definition.

Answer (score 3):

I think a single repository (backed up, of course) with individual project directories below it should suffice:

```
/usr/share/code_repository
   /base
      /trunk
      /branches
      /tags
   /project1
      /trunk
      /branches
      /tags
   /project2
      /trunk
      /branches
      /tags
   ...
```

So base is the core code and project1, project2, ...projectN would contain the variations of the base. When you checkout projectN, you would also check out base and have links to base from within Project1.

An alternative to doing it this way would be to simply have one repo with the core in it and make a branch for each variation. That is, if the core is one, big chunk and your variations are really simply variations.

This seems more a question of code packaging architecture than version control structure.

Comment: this is the way i like so each project has its separate tags/branches.

Comment: Does SVN maintain the revision number per-repository or per-project? With this layout, doesn't a revision number in project2 change the most-up-to-date number in project1?

Comment: Would it make sense to organize into organization/project ? As I said, we have lots of projects.

Comment: Sure, but why does that matter?

Comment: @matt svn maintains revisions per repository

Comment: @matt yes it will change, but it doesn't matters (IMO)

Comment: @Mike Caron - just for organization

Comment: @ScottE Organization/Project doesn't make sense. Suppose org1 owns project1, but later on org2 takes it on. Because you've organized projects under organizations, you're left with a bit of a hairy maintenance problem. Why complicate it? If each org had it's own repository, that's different; projects can be imported to other repos if organizational changes take place (whether you can keep the commit messages, I don't know off hand).

Comment: @Mike Caron - I should clarify - when I say organizatio, I mean client. Lots of clients, often lots of projects per client.

Comment: @ScottE How is the IP ownership structured? I would probably argue for 1 repository per IP ownership node, then there is clear separation on the legal side of things. However, if your clients have already agreed with your reuse of their code in other, future projects, then go with my original recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Create different projects as different repositories (on same machine). So that you can control change mailing list for each project separately :)

Comment: Having it setup as multiple repositories may be a serious limitation for the OP as they state that they will likely have "hundreds of projects". 

IMO, it would be easier to maintain a single repository from a setup/maintanence/backup perspective. If you need customized commit-emails based upon projects, (again IMO,) you should customize your post-commit-send-email script accordingly. ....and keep your hook-scripts versioned in a repository as well!

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about subversion is that you don't really have to care about that so much in the beginning.

Because you can move around files and folders inside the repository without losing their history, you could just start out with whatever you think is right and see if it works for you.

If it doesn't it can be changed later without too many problems.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is "Whatever works best for you".

There are people who will tell you of the advantages of this way over that way, but at the end of the day, having project->{trunk, tags, branches} or {trunk, tags, branches}->project, or if you have a releases branch or if you rename these to anything else or have other named items in there or remove some of the named items is all down to how you and your colleagues work and what fits best with your development cycle.

However, from what you have said I would suggest the following:

```
repository
    core
        trunk
        branches
        tags
    project1
        trunk
        branches
        tags
    project3
        trunk
        branches
        tags
```

The advantage of this is that you will be able to link each project to different versions of the core, which will be inside the core/tags folder while still allowing development of the core.  This is only my suggestion.  Your mindset may vary

Comment: you are correct but I feel project->{trunk, tags, branches} a lot easier otherwise you need to search your tag/branch of a project among zillion others :-)

Comment: exactly, Rats, however you can never account for the weird way some people work

Comment: aberrant80, I think Rats made that comment while I was editing for clarity, adding the last bit including the structure I use

Answer (score 0):

It's a subjective question so you may want to modify the tags.

Assuming you're asking about development projects, you'd have to clarify as to what sort of development you're doing. Different languages or project types usually result in different "standards".

The traditional SVN structure as inherited from CVS is to have `trunk`, `branches`, and `tags` sitting in side the main project directory. That would be duplicated for every separate project directory.

For interdependent projects, I personally prefer

```
root/somepath
  trunk
    myproject
  branches
    branch1
      myproject
    branch2
      myproject
  tags
    tag1
      myproject
    tag2
      myproject
```

This makes it easier to check out all projects that are tagged with the same tag/branch.

But it's highly dependent on your build scripts and how you plan on having developers or users check out. What's best is what's logical and efficient for your projects.